# Show that SO(2) is isomorphic with the complex circle group

Tags: group-theory, functions, complex-numbers, rotations

For my math study I have to prove that $SO(2)$ is isomorphic with the complex circle group. Some steps in this prove are a bit difficult to me, so I hope you could help me.

With $SO(2)$ I mean the group of all rotations $\rho_{x}$ in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ with $x$ the angle of rotation around the origin. With $U_{1}$ I mean the complex circle group, so $U_{1}$ = {$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1$}.

This is what I've done so far:

I defined $f: SO(2) \to U_{1}$ with $f(\rho_{x}) = e^{2\pi ix}$ and proved that it is an homomorphism and that it is surjective. So the only things I have to do is proving that $f$ is well-defined and injective.For injectivity, I have come so far:

Assume $f(\rho_{x}) = f(\rho_{y})$ $\Rightarrow$ $e^{2\pi ix} = e^{2\pi iy}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$

How do I have to complete the injectivity prove and prove that $f$ is well-defined?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think $f$ should be defined with $f(\rho_x)=\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$. For injectivity, since it is an homomorphism, all you have to check is that $\ker f=\bigl\{\operatorname{Id}\bigr\}$.

Comment: Ok, I think I completed the injectivity prove. But how to prove that f is well-defined?

Comment: Ask yourself what relation exists between $x$ and $x'$ if $\rho_x=\rho_{x'}$.

Comment: Then x - x' is a multiple of 2pi. But how do I complete the prove if I know that?

Comment: You just have to check the images by $f$ are the same. It's straightforward if you changed the definition of $f$.

Comment: Yes, I now that. But if x - x' is a multiple of 2pi, I don't see why it must be true that e^ix = e^iy. Sorry for my slow understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21361/discussion-between-peter-and-bernard).

Comment: How do we do that?

Comment: if e^ix = e^ix' then x - x' lies in Z, right? I just don't see how to combine that with the fact that x - x' is a multiple of 2pi

Comment: No $x\equiv x'\mod 2\pi$. I think you're messing up with the old definition of $f$.

Comment: Ok, and that follows directly from x - x' is a multiple of 2pi?

Comment: That's Euler's relation: $\,\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i \pi}=1$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! it's a pity that you answered in a comment, otherwise I would have rated your answer up

Comment: No problem. The essential fact is that I could help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternately, one can show this, while avoiding checking well-definedness manually, using the First Isomorphism Theorem.

First observe for concreteness (i.e., making easier writing down certain maps later) that:

1. The element in $SO(2)$ that corresponds to (anticlockwise) rotation by $x$ revolutions (equivalently, $2 \pi x$ radians) can be written as the rotation matrix
   $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos 2 \pi x & -\sin 2\pi x\\ \sin 2 \pi x& \cos 2 \pi x\end{pmatrix};$$ in particular, the representation has the feature that group multiplication in $SO(2)$ is just (the restriction of) matrix multiplication.
2. Any element in $U_1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ can be written as $$e^{2 \pi i x} = \cos 2 \pi x + i \sin 2\pi x.$$

This suggests a correspondence
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos 2 \pi x & -\sin 2\pi x\\ \sin 2 \pi x& \cos 2 \pi x\end{pmatrix} \leftrightarrow e^{2 \pi i x} = \cos 2 \pi x + i \sin 2\pi x.$$

We now formalize this idea: Define a map $F: \mathbb{R} \to SO(2)$ by
$$F : x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\cos 2 \pi x & -\sin 2\pi x\\ \sin 2 \pi x& \cos 2 \pi x\end{pmatrix};$$
one can readily show that it is surjective, and using the usual angle sum identities shows that it is a homomorphism. Now, $\ker F = \mathbb{Z}$, so by the F.I.T., $F$ descends to an isomorphism $$\tilde{F}: \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \text{im } F = SO(2).$$
Similarly, one can induce an isomorphism $\tilde{G}: \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cong}{\to} U_1$.