# $SO(2)$homeomorphic to $U(1)$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $SU(2)$ homoemorphic to $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: general-topology

I am starting with topology right now. On our current exercise sheet, we are asked to prove that the special orthogonal group $SO(2)$ is homeomorphic to $U(1)$ and to $\mathbb{S}^1$ and to prove that $SU(2)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^3$. I dont have any idea how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161594/show-that-so2-is-isomorphic-with-the-complex-circle-group

Comment: Please check the title of your question.